# Select join two tables with Zend DB

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, select, join

I have 2 tables: users and user_profile:

```
users: (user_id, email, password, created_date)

user_profile: (user_id, first_name, last_name, address, birthday)
```

Using Zend DB select I want to join these two tables (like this)

```
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id`=`user_profile`.`user_id`
```

The problem now is I don't know how to achieve this with Select join by using Zend_Db.
Please help me out. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$select = $this->select()
                ->from('users')
                ->joinLeft(array('userprofile'=>'user_profile'),'users.user_id = userprofile.user_id')
                ->where('users.user_id = ?', 1);
```

This is how you join two tables in zend. Check the ZF manual for advances usages of the zend join [zend.db.select.building.join](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join)